# Insert not working in Mongo Stitch (JS)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am currently trying to insert a document to my mongodb but when I call insert() on a collection, an error is produced saying (FacilitatorJS.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: db.collection(...).insert is not a function
    at db.collection.find.execute.then.result (FacilitatorJS.js:26)
    at )

Could anyone help with this? I've tried insertOne() with no luck either.

Here's the code below

```
//prep server connection
    const clientPromise = stitch.StitchClientFactory.create('CODE');
    var client;
    var db;
    let stitchClient;
    /**
     * Connects to DB and can retrieve a facilitator's existing id, or create a new one (if name doesnt exist in db)
     * @param {dict} name //name to find or insert
     */
    function connect(name){
        clientPromise.then(stitchClient =>{
            client = stitchClient;
            db = client.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db('budgetopolis');

            return client.login().then(getFacilitatorID(name))
        });
    }
    function getFacilitatorID(name){
        db.collection('Facilitators').find(name).execute().then(result => {
            if(result.length == 0){
                //create a facilitator object in db if doesn't exist
                db.collection("Facilitators").insert(name).execute().then(result1 => {
                    //now get the newly added Facilitator's ID
                    console.log('created new user')
                    db.collection('Facilitators').find(name).execute().then(result2 => {
                        var fullId = result[0]['_id']
                        Facilitator.session_id = fullId.toString().slice(-4)
                        updateMessageBar("Your new session id is: " + Facilitator.session_id)
                    });
                });
            }else{ //working
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: db.collection(...).insert is not a function at db.collection.find.execute.then.result (FacilitatorJS.js:26) at )

There is no function called `insert()` for a collection on the [stitch-sdk JavaScript](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/master/index.html#collection). You should use `insertOne()` instead. If you have tried with `insertOne()`, the error line probably differs.

I would suggest to follow one of the [MongoDB Tutorials: Stitch](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/tutorials/) to get started.